# Which datatype is better for large values in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Datatype here i used in the scenario is : `long`

When i am inserting documents with fields more than 15 digits the response in ES 2.4.0 is good but when i am inserting values that are more than 15 digits it is `rounding of`.

1) `"field":458585784525458` -->the response is same
2) `"field":89632567523695856` -->the response is not 89632567523695800

May i know why, because of this my search mechanism is totally wrong.

Thanks

Comment: How about using `long long` ?

Comment: how about storing it in a string

Comment: Thanks rahul for your suggestion .. The problem is with not ES it is with Sense plugin which i am using to send the data to ES.Since it uses javascript https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15292